# Can't add Flurry to my Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, flurry

I've stuck with a Flurry: I add Flurry (Analytics only) to my swift project according this guide:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios-manual/

After all steps done it throws error:

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar one?

Comment: There are several possibilities. Can you post your bridging header and a screenshot of the project nav menu?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like library not found.

Check **Link Library With Libraries** on Build Phases in Xcode.

Read documentation about Import Flurry Libraries:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios-manual/?guccounter=1#import-flurry-libraries

Comment: Umm, sorry. I just guest the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I integrated Flurry it works perfectly. You are making mistake here,you are opening project using this `projectname.xcodeproj` rather than this file `projectname.xcworkspace` . After install pod you must open project using this `projectname.xcworkspace`

For your reference i updated sample project please take a look if you could not get it. [Sample Project](https://github.com/shauket/FlurrySample.git)

Comment: no mistakes ) I use .xcworkspace (I have a lot of dependencies in my project)

Comment: then its not an issue with Flurry. Flurry works as expected. i refer this solution because i got same error whenever open this file .xcodeproj

Comment: you can try other way to fix it. just run these commands again, pod update , pod install